# Jitterbit Dynamic Path

Tags: jitterbit

I have a requirement in which there are two fields in which One is Picklist value.

I want to call for a dynamic Path and compare the fields in Salesforce.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information about what you are asking for?  If you mean that you just want to dynamically pick one field or another, based on some criteria, that can be done with a simple if, case, or condition (depending on exactly what you are doing).

Also not sure what you mean by you want to "call for a dynamic path."  Anything can be dynamically set via variables.  But, you'll have to provide some more information as to exactly what you are trying to do.